# java - about Google Calendar API v3

Tags: java, oauth

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate?hl=zh-CN

```
I would like to use Google Calendar API v3, but in this example, I can't find these libraries:

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenResponse; 
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource; 
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant; 
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl; 

Perhaps they are too old and deprecated? and where can I get the latest examples for authorization codes?
```

Comment: Perhaps you might like to read this http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10.  While I'm not experienced with it, it might lead you the direction you need to go

Answer (score 0):

fyI: I've got an official answer from Google that they are going to update the outdated documentation and examples with examples using the new API (v3).

Comment: Why give me a negative rating for posting an official answer I got from the Google team? ...